# Изменение максимальной длины значений столбца SAL

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Ребята! Подскажите пожалуйста! В Oracle я новичок!! Измените максимальную длину значений столбца SAL до 9 знаков (из них 2 после запятой) в таблице EMP_NEW.
Всем спасибо!)

Comment: Хорошо, мы изменим у себя размер этой колонки. А на этом сайте не принято помогать с домашними заданиями и т.п. goole: "oracle alter table" вам поможет

Comment: google: `oracle alter table modify column number precision` в точку

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table EMP_NEW modify SAL number(7,2);
```